# Ruby on Rails MySQL query confusion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to make my code much simply and efficient. My code goes like this (in MODEL)

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, AvatarUploader

  def self.search(search)
      if search
        where(('(name LIKE ? OR name = ?) AND (employee_type = "SE" OR employee_type = "OP")'), "%#{search}%", "")
    else
      unscoped
    end
  end
end
```

and my controller goes like this:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
    @employees = Employee.search(params[:employee_type])
    @employees = Employee.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
  end 
end
```

Comment: @xdazz thanks dude!

Comment: it looks like you are over riding your variable in the controller @employees 3 times

Comment: @MZarogaza 
Ah I see. I'm just new in RoR :D

Comment: what is the end goal

Comment: What is it that you want to do?

Comment: "what is the end goal"
=> I'd like to use the WHERE in the model. I'm having hard time about it

Comment: Well I am asking what is the question?

Comment: where(('(name LIKE ? OR name = ?) AND (employee_type = "SE" OR employee_type = "OP")'), "%#{search}%", "")
I'm having trouble with the above query. Did I make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wou can start by doing something like this

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction

  def index
    if params[:employee_type].present?
      @employees = Employee.search(params[:employee_type])
    elsif params[:search].present?
      @employees = Employee.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    else
      @employees = Employee.all
    end
  end 
end
```

now you wont over ride your variables

Comment: Thanks @Mzaragoza! I didn't know we can put conditional statements in controller :D Thanks!

Comment: @reynantedaitol I am glad to help :)